# Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.50)
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.3.50/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar'.
>   Connection reset
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44m 49s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 0):

you may have **net problem**. Check connection and try again. This may solve your problem